# Class average with functions and structures

Tags: c

**Nevermind! I got it to work thank to all of you guys help. I'll post the solution as soon as I get back.**

Bascially, I'm just trying to find the class average based on the user-input values for a structure database. Everything is working except I can't seem to get the right output for the class average of a specific assignment.

Here's the function I'm struggling with:

**EDIT** (I changed up the function but the older version is still in the full code snippet.)

For example I'll input:
001 100 100 100

002 50 50 50

-1 0 0 0 (To terminate)

The output would be:

The class homework average is 150.00.

(But it should be 75.00)

> void classavg(struct Grade record[200])
>   {

```
int i;
char  assign[30];
double classavghw = 0, classavge1 = 0, classavge2 = 0, totalhw = 0, totale1 = 0, totale2 = 0;

    i = 0;
    while(record[i].euid != -1)
    {

        totalhw += record[i].hwavg;

        totale1 += record[i].exam1;

        totale2 += record[i].exam2;

        classavghw = totalhw/i;
        classavge1 = totale1/i;
        classavge2 = totale2/i;

        i++;
    }


    printf("Enter the assignment: (homework, exam1, exam2)\n");
    scanf("%s", assign);

    if(strcmp(assign, "homework") == 0)
    {
        printf("The class homework average is: %.2lf\n", classavghw);
    }
    else if(strcmp(assign, "exam1") == 0)
    {
        printf("The class exam1 average is: %.2lf\n", classavge1);
    }
    else if(strcmp(assign, "exam2") == 0)
    {
        printf("The class exam2 average is: %.2lf\n", classavge2);
    }
    else

        printf("Not a valid input!\n");
```

}

Here's the full code:

```html
/*
CSCE Homework 05:
HEADER:
Author: Laura Kent (LauraKent@my.unt.edu) lek0073
Date: 11/9/2014
CSCE 1030
Purpose:
*/

#include <stdio.h>

struct Grade
{
   int euid;
   double hwavg;
   double exam1;
   double exam2;

};

void headerinfo(void);
void menu(void);
void database(struct Grade record[200]);
void studentinfo(struct Grade record[200]);
void studentavg(struct Grade record[200]);
void letteravg(int);
void classavg(struct Grade record[200]);

int main()

{

 struct Grade record[200];

 headerinfo();

 char assign[30];

 database(record);

 int input;

 while(1)
 {

  menu();

  scanf("%d",&input);

  switch(input)
  {
   case 1:

    studentinfo(record);

    break;

   case 2:

    studentavg(record);

    break;

   case 3:

    classavg(record);

    break;

   case 4:

    printf("Terminating program: Bye-bye!\n");
    return 0;
    break;

   default:

    printf("Error! Invalid input.\n\n");


  }

 }


}

void headerinfo(void)
{

 printf("Program: Homwork05.c\nAuthor: Laura Kent (LauraKent@my.unt.edu) lek0073\nCSCE 1030\n");
}

void menu(void)
{

 printf("Select one of the following:\n 1. Student grade data \n 2. Student grade average \n 3. Class average for assignment \n 4. Exit\n");

}

void database(struct Grade record[200])
{

 int i;

 printf("Input each student's EUID, homework average, exam 1 grade, and exam 2 grade: \n\n");

 printf("To terminate input '-1' as the student EUID, along with throwaway values for the average and grades.\n");

 for(i=0; i<200; ++i)
 {

  scanf("%d %lf %lf %lf", &record[i].euid, &record[i].hwavg, &record[i].exam1, &record[i].exam2);

  if(record[i].euid == -1)
  {
   break;
  }

 }
}

void studentinfo(struct Grade record[200])

{
 int i, x;

 printf("Enter the student's EUID:\n");

 scanf("%d", &x);

 i = 0;

 while(record[i].euid != -1 && record[i].euid != x)
 {
      i++;
 }

 printf("EUID:%d  Homework:  %.2f  Exam 1:%.0f  Exam2:  %.0f\n", record[i].euid, record[i].hwavg, record[i].exam1, record[i].exam2);

}

void studentavg(struct Grade record[200])

{
 int i, x;
 float gradeavg;

 printf("Enter the student's EUID:\n");

 scanf("%d", &x);

 i = 0;

 while(record[i].euid != -1 && record[i].euid !=x)
 {
  i++;
 }

 gradeavg = (record[i].hwavg * 0.5) + (record[i].exam1 * 0.25) + (record[i].exam2 * 0.25);

 printf("EUID:%d  Grade average:%.2lf\n", record[i].euid, gradeavg);

 letteravg(gradeavg);


}

void letteravg(average)

{

 char letter;

 if(average > 89.50)
 {
  letter = 'A';
 }
 else if(average <= 89.4999 && average > 79.50)
 {
  letter = 'B';
 }
 else if(average <= 79.4999 && average > 69.50)
 {
  letter = 'C';
 }
 else if(average <= 69.4999 && average > 59.50)
 {
  letter = 'D';
 }
 else
 {
  letter = 'F';
 }

 printf("Letter grade:%c\n", letter);
}

void classavg(struct Grade record[200])
{


 int i;
 char  assign[30];
 double classavghw = 0, classavge1 = 0, classavge2 = 0, totalhw = 0, totale1 = 0, totale2 = 0;

  i = 0;
  while(record[i].euid != -1)
  {

   totalhw += record[i].hwavg;

   totale1 += record[i].exam1;

   totale2 += record[i].exam2;

   classavghw = totalhw/i;
   classavge1 = totale1/i;
   classavge2 = totale2/i;

   i++;
  }


  printf("Enter the assignment: (homework, exam1, exam2)\n");
  scanf("%s", assign);

  if(strcmp(assign, "homework") == 0)
  {
   printf("The class homework average is: %.2lf\n", classavghw);
  }
  else if(strcmp(assign, "exam1") == 0)
  {
   printf("The class exam1 average is: %.2lf\n", classavge1);
  }
  else if(strcmp(assign, "exam2") == 0)
  {
   printf("The class exam2 average is: %.2lf\n", classavge2);
  }
  else

   printf("Not a valid input!\n");


}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the given results and the expected results?  Also you should initialize your double values before using +=.  There could be anything at that memory location, and you are assuming it is 0.

Comment: You need to initialize your variables. Also, are you sure that you want to increment `i` in the loop body before adding to totals? It looks to me like incrementing `i` should be the last statement in the loop body.

Comment: you cannot use the string functions on a non-terminated string. so initialize the assign array to all '\0' before calling scanf().  Otherwise undefined behaviour will result, possibly resulting in a seg fault event.

Comment: regarding this line: scanf("%s", assign);  the returned value from the call to scanf() should be checked to assure that the conversion to the assign array was successful.  Also, there is nothing limiting the length of the input, so the assign array could be overrun, resulting in undefined behaviour.  It would be better to use something like fgets() to read the input into a local buffer, then check the number of characters input,  then use sscanf() to extract the string. OR, more simply.  char assign[30] = {'\0'}; then; scanf("%29s", assign); // 29 allows for string terminator

Answer (score 0):

You did not post the whole code, but in first look, it seems, your problem is you never initialized

```
double classavghw, classavge1, classavge2, totalhw, totale1, totale2;
```

these variables.

Also, in your code, in `while()` loop, you are incrementing `i` too early [unless that's a design requirement, can't be sure without full code]. Usually, index `i` should be incremented after the loop performs the addition.

Maybe if you edit and add more info, we can have some more clues.